# Lock SQL server table for a read-write operation

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table where the primary key is an increment int 'ID', that I have to manually set. I know an autoincrement int (IDENTITY) should have been the best option, but I can't change the existing table design.

So I need to atomize the operation of Read-Write, in some sort of:

- Lock table
- Read the MAX value of existings ID
- Add new record with Primary Key = ID+1
- Release table

What is the correct way to lock the table in a multiuser environment? I suppose it's a mix of transactions and the use of TABLOCX. I need to ensure:

- No deadlocks
- If something fails, the table should no stay locked (for example, program fails and exits when triying to write, and no COMMIT/ROLLBACK is called). I don't know even if this could be possible.

NOTE: The database is also used by other applications that I suppose care themselves of this problem.

EDITED: Could this be considered enough atomic to be a solution?:

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, OtherFields...) VALUES ((Select Max(ID)+1 from MYTABLE), 'values'...)

Comment: The "other applications" are inserting to this table too?

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, the other applications are INSERTING

Comment: Could this be considered enough atomic to be a solution?: INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, OtherFields...) VALUES ((Select Max(ID)+1 from MYTABLE), 'values'...)

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to roll your own auto-increment mechanism using table locks is almost bound to fail - however, since you wrote you can't change the existing table, I would suggest using a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the next number instead of locking the table.

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.MySequence -- Don't use this name, please!
    AS int -- note: default is bigInt
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 
    NO CYCLE;
```

This has <strike>all</strike> some<sup>**1**</sup> of the benefits of an identity column, without having to add an identity column to your table.

You can also use the sequence to generate a default value to a column (assuming adding a default constraint doesn't count as "changing the existing table structure", of course). [See example D in official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples)

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableName
    ADD CONSTRAINT YourTableName_id_default  
    DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR MySequence 
    FOR Id;
```

<sup>**1**</sup> The benefits are you don't need to add locks or to calculate the next number yourself.
However, you should know that unlike an identity column, this doesn't protect you from updates to the id column, nor does it protect you from insert statements that explicitly insert a value to this column (without using `next value for`).

The first problem can be quite easily solved with an instead-of-update trigger on the table that will only update columns that aren't the id column, but I'm not sure how to solve the other problem.

Comment: If other applications are inserting to the table the sequence will get out of synch as it won't know about those inserts - so it would also need changes to those applications

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm not sure I understand. I was under the impression that a sequence can be viewed as a stand-alone identity producer. What do you mean by "out of synch"?

Comment: If there are other applications that are currently inserting to the table then they must be inserting an explicit value for the `ID` column (so won't use the default without changes) - presumably they are also doing some variant of `MAX(ID) + 1` so if the table's max id is 6 and the sequence is at 6 but the other application inserts 7 then the next value generated by the sequence will clash with that

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh I see what you mean now.

Comment: @MartinSmith Maybe an INSTEAD OF trigger to replace those with the SEQUENCE value? (just spitballing here)

Comment: @RBarryYoung Nice idea, but how can you tell which insert includes a value generated from the sequence and which includes some other value? Basically, I believe that could work but it might over-use the sequence values.  I hope Martin will answer that question, though. His knowledge of SQL Server is far superior to mine.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Agreed, Martin rules. ;-) But the OP is already talking about doing things that would have to interfere with and/or supplant those processes.  One solution might be for the SEQUENCE to use a specific zone/range outside of the expected ranges of the current code (something like how replicated IDs are generated) and then duck the values that are in the client-code's expected range.

Comment: It's exactly what @MartinSmith says. There is another application using the database (the one this database was created for). It's programmed in Access. I talked them and they say that they use that algorithm (Lock, Calculate Max(ID)+1, Insert, Release). So I think I can't use the sequene :(

Comment: Then I would look into @RBarryYoung's idea - adding an instead of insert trigger on the table and have it insert the id values using the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

So if the other process is correctly handling the locking, you could do exactly what you mentioned (lock, get last ID, insert and release) by executing something similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @MaxID INT

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        SELECT
            @MaxID = MAX(I.ID)
        FROM 
            MyTable AS I WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK) -- TABLOCKX: no operations can be done, HOLDLOCK: until the end of the transaction

        INSERT INTO MyTable (
            ID,
            OtherColumn)
        SELECT
            ID = ISNULL(@MaxID + 1, 1)
            OtherColumn = 'Other values'

    COMMIT

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    
    -- Handle your error logging and rollback the transaction so the table locks are released, a basic example:
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE()

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK

    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 16, 1)

END CATCH
```

However you will still have to do additional stuff for batch inserts, or if you need the inserted ID to load other related tables.

Also `TABLOCKX` is pretty restrictive, there are other less-restrictive locks but I believe they might leave you open for concurrency issues. You can check other locking hints in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15).